# Image alignment using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have a HTML input used to search items on a MySQL table.
And I must say I am new to CSS.
This is the HTMP part:

```
<div id="main">


        <div class="icon"></div>
        <h1 class="title">Especialidad Médica</h1>
        <h5 class="title">(selecciona la especialidad médica del doctor)</h5>

        <!-- Main Input -->
        <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">

        <!-- Show Results -->
        <h4 id="results-text">Mostrando resultados para: <b id="search-string">Array</b></h4>
        <ul id="results"></ul>


    </div>
```

And this is the CSS part:

```
/******************************************************************
Main CSS
******************************************************************/
div#main {
    width: 360px;
    margin: 200px auto 20px auto;
}
.title {
    line-height: 1.2em;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
div.icon {
    margin-top: 4px;
    float: left;
    width: 31px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(../images/magnify.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-position, color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
    -moz-transition-property: background-position, color;
    -moz-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
    -ms-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
    -ms-transition-timing-property: linear, linear;
    -o-transition-property: background-position, color;
    -o-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
    -o-transition-timing-property: linear, linear;
    transition-property: background-position, color;
    transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
    transition-timing-property: linear, linear;
}
div.icon:hover {
    background-position: 0px -30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input#search {
    width: 350px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 25px;
    color: #ababab;
}
input#search:hover, input#search:focus {
    color: #3b3b3b;
    border: 1px solid #36a2d2;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
h4#results-text {
    display: none;
}
ul#results {
    display: none;
    width: 360px;
    margin-top: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) 0 1px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.15) 0 1px 3px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) 0 1px 3px;
}
ul#results li {
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
}
ul#results li:hover {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
ul#results li:first-child {
    border-top: none;
}
ul#results li h3, ul#results li h4 {
    transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
    color: #616161;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
ul#results li:hover h3, ul#results li:hover h4  {
    color: #3b3b3b;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I am using AJAX to get the results from a PHP file.

And this is the PHP part:

```
// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';

$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<img src="iconos_especialidades/logo"  width="94" height="94"  />';
$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';
$html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';

// Get Search
$search_string = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", " ", $_POST['query']);
$search_string = $tutorial_db->real_escape_string($search_string);

// Check Length More Than One Character
if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {
    // Build Query
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tb_especialidades WHERE especialidad LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%" OR especialidad LIKE "%'.$search_string.'%"';

    // Do Search
    $result = $tutorial_db->query($query);
    while($results = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $result_array[] = $results;
    }

    // Check If We Have Results
    if (isset($result_array)) {
        foreach ($result_array as $result) {

            // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
            $display_function = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['especialidad']);
            $display_name = preg_replace("/".$search_string."/i", "<b class='highlight'>".$search_string."</b>", $result['especialidad']);
            $display_url = 'opinar_doc_local.php';

            if ($result['icono'] == ""){
            $display_logo = "nada.jpg";
            }
            else {
            $display_logo = $result['icono'] ;
            }

            // Insert Name
            $output = str_replace('nameString', $display_name, $html);



            // Insert URL
            $output = str_replace('urlString', $display_url, $output);
            // Insert LOGO
            $output = str_replace('logo', $display_logo, $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
        }
    }else{

        // Format No Results Output
        $output = str_replace('urlString', 'javascript:void(0);', $html);
        $output = str_replace('nameString', '<b>No se ha encontrado la especialidad buscada.</b>', $output);
        $output = str_replace('functionString', 'Sorry :(', $output);

        // Output
        echo($output);
    }
}
```

My issue is that I want to get the image on the left side of the div and the text on the right sight of the image, the text should be aligned vertically to the middle of the image.

That is the current output:

[image]

I have tried adding this to the CSS file:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But the output is the same.

Comment: if you can provide work code it will be better. i think best solution is to use dismal: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; on both image and text <div>

Comment: @AdnanAkram, what do you mean with work code?

Comment: He meant - not php code, we can't do anything with it. It's better to create snippet or bin so we actually see the problem a live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this one, if add `display-inline-block; and vertical-align: middle;`  on both image and `<h3>`  then both image and `<h3>` will be in middle of each other, but keep one thing in mind, you need to add width on both to make this work.

```css
ul#results li img{display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
ul#results li h3{display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;}
```

```html
<ul id="results">
  <li>
    <img src="http://www.redsignal.net/staging/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/6_ui_ux_design_hov.png"/>
    <h3>  your txt her </h3>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using display flex on list

```
li.result {
 display:flex;
}
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeep1991singh/JKZLe/60/)

Answer (score 0):

Try floating the img and the link

```
.result img,.result a {
  float:left;
}
```

Note: if the link width is grater then the space left the link will pop down
to fix that you will need to set a fixed with to the link

Comment: Thank you madalin, but your proposal puts the images on wrong places